# Maven Install fails Under linux environment due to case sensitivity

Tags: node.js, maven, compiler-errors, case-insensitive

mvn install fails under linux(RedHat) environment due to the fact that checkout operation checksout the file as, say **S**ome**F**ile.js however there are some javascripts that reference it as some**F**ile.js and this leads to failure throwing .

```
Tracing dependencies for: /path/of/the/file/plugins.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'look/up/filepath/someFile.js'
```

is there a way to tell mvn command to do a case insensitive operation on the file ?

Note: The same works under windows environment and also works if I would rename the file, which I don't want to.

thanks in advance.
J

Comment: You have to fix the issue by correctly renaming the files...cause Windows is case insensitve but linux/unix is...

Comment: thanks for your response @khmarbaise. However that exactly what I mention in the Note: that I don't want to do this cause we are migrating  applications under linux slaves and that would mean a lot of file refactoring files which we don't want to do.

Comment: Is there no way to force maven windows applications to use case sensitive file names and paths? That way you can ensure that the file structure is the same regardless of the environment it runs in